# Error creating bean with name springSecurityFilterChain No configuration setting found for key security when starting Para with LDAP config

Tags: spring, configuration, para, scoold

I'm trying the product Para and Scoold.
When I launch Para (https://github.com/Erudika/para) with the default configuration, it works fine.
When I add the configuration for LDAP and I launch Para, then I get the exception below.
Is there a missing configuration among the LDAP settings?

This is the default configuration

```
# the name of the root app
para.app_name = "Para"
# or set it to 'production'
para.env = "embedded"
# if true, users can be created without verifying their emails
para.security.allow_unverified_emails = false
# if hosting multiple apps on Para, set this to false
para.clients_can_access_root_app = true
# if false caching is disabled
para.cache_enabled = true
# root app secret, used for token generation, should be a random string
para.app_secret_key = "b8db69a25553f2ce134909f164665263"
# enable API request signature verification
para.security.api_security = true
# the node number from 1 to 1024, used for distributed ID generation
para.worker_id = 1
```

This is the LDAP configuration added to the default one

```
#URL of the LDAP server, including scheme and port.
para.security.ldap.server_url = ldap://pippo.pluto.local:389


#The base DN, aka domain.
para.security.ldap.base_dn = ou=pippo,dc=pippo,dc=local



#The initial bind DN for a user with search privileges. The value of this property cannot contain whitespaces. Those will automatically be escaped with %20. Usually this value is left blank
para.security.ldap.bind_dn =cn=pippo,ou=Admin


#The password for a user with search privileges. Usually this value is left blank.
para.security.ldap.bind_pass = pippi
```

This is the exception

```
2020-01-15 15:46:34,103 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.Para - --- Para.initialize() [embedded] ---
2020-01-15 15:46:34,103 [INFO ] c.erudika.para.core.utils.CoreUtils - Loaded new DAO, Search and Cache implementations - MockDAO, MockSearch and CaffeineCache.
2020-01-15 15:46:34,135 [WARN ] com.erudika.para.utils.HealthUtils - Server is unhealthy - root app not found. Open /v1/_setup in the browser to initialize Para.
2020-01-15 15:46:34,150 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.Para - Instance #1 initialized.
2020-01-15 15:46:34,900 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.ParaServer - Starting ParaServer on pippoLAB1 with PID 13012 (C:\Program Files\Para\para-jar-1.34.2.jar started by pippoLAB1$ in C:\Program Files\Para)
2020-01-15 15:46:34,900 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.ParaServer - The following profiles are active: embedded
2020-01-15 15:46:35,713 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.ParaServer - Listening on port 8090...
2020-01-15 15:46:37,228 [WARN ] o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3b07a0d6{/,[file:///C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-docbase.9117481678924898909.8090/],UNAVAILABLE}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.configure(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.<init>(JettyWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getJettyWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:401)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.erudika.para.ParaServer.runAsJAR(ParaServer.java:447)
    at com.erudika.para.ParaServer.main(ParaServer.java:455)
    at com.erudika.para.Run.main(Run.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:149)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:268)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:41)
    at com.erudika.para.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
    at com.erudika.para.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a857a999.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
2020-01-15 15:46:37,244 [WARN ] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty web server
2020-01-15 15:46:37,244 [INFO ] com.erudika.para.Para - --- Para.destroy() ---
2020-01-15 15:46:37,260 [ERROR] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.erudika.para.ParaServer.runAsJAR(ParaServer.java:447)
    at com.erudika.para.ParaServer.main(ParaServer.java:455)
    at com.erudika.para.Run.main(Run.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.<init>(JettyWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getJettyWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:401)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.configure(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:108)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: empty config: No configuration setting found for key 'security'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:149)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:268)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:41)
    at com.erudika.para.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
    at com.erudika.para.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a857a999.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a configuration problem. 
 1. Configuration values should be in quotes, e.g.:

```
para.security.ldap.server_url = "ldap://pippo.pluto.local:389"
```

2. LDAP configuration properties belong in the configuration file for Scoold.
3. Para is not initialized, open `GET /v1/_setup` in your browser.

The steps to run both Para and Scoold locally are these:

1. [run Para locally on port 8080](https://paraio.org/docs/#001-intro) and initialize it with `GET localhost:8080/v1/_setup`
2. Save the access keys for the root Para app somewhere safe, you'll need them to configure Para CLI tool below
3. Create a new directory for Scoold containing its own *dedicated* `application.conf` and configure it to connect to Para on port `8080`
4. Start Scoold with `java -jar -Dserver.port=8000 -Dconfig.file=./application.conf scoold.jar` OR `mvn spring-boot:run`
5. Open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser

Use the [Para CLI](https://github.com/Erudika/para-cli) tool to create a separate app for Scoold:

```sh
$ npm install -g para-cli
# run setup and enter the keys for the root app and endpoint 'http://localhost:8080'
$ para-cli setup
$ para-cli ping
$ para-cli new-app "scoold" --name "Scoold"
```

Finally, add the LDAP configuration to `scoold_folder/application.conf` and restart Scoold.